# How to resolve the access denied error in SharePoint?

Tags: access-denied

This is the below code which I used to get the web reference using the title of the web site. The problem is the current user is not a member of all sub site so I'm getting access denied error.

User A have rights to: Web1, Web2 (no problem with code)

User B have rights to: Web1 (problem with code because he doesn't have rights to web2)

```
int projectid = GetProjectID(SPContext.Current.Web.Title, Url);

string projecttitle = SPContext.Current.Web.Title;

var nodename = currentWeb.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>().FirstOrDefault(node =>
node.Title == projecttitle);
```

Comment: On what row is the access denied coming from? If it is in GetProjectID method, please show us from what row in that.

Comment: var nodename = currentWeb.ChildNodes.Cast().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Title == projecttitle);

Comment: Added an answer, but is there a reason (performance, perhaps) why you are using SiteMapNode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser

to get only subwebs current user has access to.

If you want to get all sites even if user doesn't have permissions to access them, use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // implementation details omitted
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrevileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx). The code inside the specified delegate will then run under the identity of the current app pool user.